# How to typeset a quotation in LaTeX that looks like one on TeX.SX?

Tags: quoting

> How do I make this table?

In stackexchange, if you type ">" at the first of the sentence, you get the above quotation.

I tried to do the same thing on LaTeX, but it did not work.

How do I make that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which table?

Comment: What is the question here? Do mean $<$ ? Or is it the missing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` problem, resulting in strange output from `<` when used in text mode?

Comment: in your title you use `<` but in the question you use `>` but I _think_ you do not want either you want a quotation such as `\begin{quote}....\end{quote}` the markdown syntax for a quote is `>` at the beginning of a line but there is essentially no similarity between markdown and latex

Comment: the ">" character results in a blockquote on SX not a table.

Comment: *I tried to do the same thing on LaTeX,* and where is your code? You should *always* post what you have tried even if it fails. In this way you can get an explanation of why it fails. Moreover give me teh codez questions aren't usually well regarded when the author puts no effort in them.

Comment: @Bakuriu, the O.P. tried to type ">" in the (La)TeX manuscript, which of course did not work out :)

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{quote}{%
  \vskip 10\p@
  \parindent\z@
  \d@ublerule
  \list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \endlist
  \d@ublerule
}
\def\d@ublerule{\hrule\@width\hsize\kern 1.5\p@\hrule\@width\hsize}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
  How do I make this table?
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

[image: output1_quote]

### Addendum

If the background should be colored you can use the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\renewenvironment{quote}{%
  \vskip 10\p@
  \parindent\z@
  \tcolorbox[
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=\z@,
    boxsep=\z@,
    left=\z@,
    right=\z@,
    top=\z@,
    bottom=\z@
  ]
  \d@ublerule
  \vskip 5\p@
  \list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \endlist
  \d@ublerule
  \endtcolorbox
}
```

[image: output2]

The final version could then be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
  \definecolor{sx-yellow}{RGB}{249,245,233}
  \definecolor{sx-orange}{RGB}{224,215,188}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{quote}{%
  \vskip 10\p@
  \parindent\z@
  \tcolorbox[
    breakable, sharp corners,
    boxrule=\z@, boxsep=\z@,
    left=\z@, right=\z@,
    top=\z@, bottom=\z@,
    colback=sx-yellow
  ]
  {\color{sx-orange}\d@ublerule}
  \vskip 5\p@
  \list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \endlist
  {\color{sx-orange}\d@ublerule}
  \endtcolorbox
  \vskip 5\p@
}
\def\d@ublerule{\hrule\@width\hsize\kern 1.5\p@\hrule\@width\hsize}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
  How do I make this table?
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

[image: output3]

[image: output_final]

Comment: Your final version imho doesn't look very good before and after a page break.

Comment: @Benjamin, I tested the final patch with sorrounding text forcing a page break. i.e. `\lipsum[1-n]\begin{quote} How do I make this table? \end{quote}\lipsum` and I can't really see what you possibly mean. Can you explain a little bit further what does not look good in your opinion?

Comment: What I mean is something like this `\begin{quote}\lipsum[1-5]\end{quote}`. So that the page break is inside the quote environment.

Comment: @Benjamin -- ok, this explains the circumstances but not the actual "misbehaviour". Anyways, I compiled your example to infer your esthetics about colored boxes spaning multiple pages and I guess you mean the padding of the borders facing the page. That is imho a prety marginal detail, not to say irrelevant. If someone likes a slight padding better he can just use your solution, or not?

Comment: Yes, I mean the padding at the beginning and end of a page. It is a matter of taste, sure. But I like my padding. ;)

Comment: @Benjamin, I knew it was the padding. Everybody loves the padding. Gottabe =D I guess, it could be helpful for future visitors of this question (even if it is that minimal), if you can add a little remark to your solution explaining how yours differs from mine.

Comment: Sure that makes sense. I added some more information

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \hline put your words here \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

This gives you

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility would be to solely use the package `tcolorbox` and define a custom environment with it. If it is not a requirement to redefine `quote` environment, this solution is imho easier to read and adjust than @Ruben's solution. Apart from that it introduces a small padding at the beginning and end when the box is too big, that a page break is necessary. Have a look at the second screenshot to get an idea what that will look like.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{F9F5E9}
\definecolor{linecolor}{HTML}{E0D7BC}
\newtcolorbox{QuoteBox}{%
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  sharp corners,
  colback=background,
  colframe=background,
  borderline north={0.5pt}{0pt}{linecolor},
  borderline north={0.5pt}{1.5pt}{linecolor},
  borderline south={0.5pt}{0pt}{linecolor},
  borderline south={0.5pt}{1.5pt}{linecolor},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{QuoteBox}
How do I make this table?
\end{QuoteBox}

\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: tcolorbox]
[image: tcolorbox_2]